# Seeding the database with a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I created a many-to-many relationship with Entity Framework Core using [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) but have a few questions:

Would it hurt anything if I add a DbSet BlogPosts to the DbContext even though they don't do it in the example?

If I don't add the DbSet to the DbContext what would be the proper way to create a Blog and then add multiple Posts to it when seeding the database. Something about the below just seems so strange. I would prefer simply creating BlogPost objects and adding them to a BlogPosts in the context.

```
var blog1 = new Blog() { Name = "ABC" };
blog1.BlogPosts.Add(new BlogPost { BlogId = blog1.Id, PostId = post1.Id });
var blog2 = new Blog() { Name = "123" };
blog2.BlogPosts.Add(new BlogPost { BlogId = blog2.Id, PostId = post1.Id });
var blog3 = new Blog() { Name = "XYZ" };
blog3.BlogPosts.Add(new BlogPost { BlogId = blog3.Id, PostId = post2.Id });
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Also, is it mandatory that I add a List navigation property to both the Blog and Post like in the example if I will only care about querying them from a single direction. i.e. Blog > Posts, don't need Post Blogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it hurt anything if I add a DbSet BlogPosts to the DbContext even though they don't do it in the example?

No. The explicit join entity (`BlogPost`) is entity like any other, so you can add (or not add) `DbSet` for it.

> If I don't add the DbSet to the DbContext what would be the proper way to create a Blog and then add multiple Posts to it when seeding the database. Something about the below just seems so strange. I would prefer simply creating BlogPost objects and adding them to a BlogPosts in the context.

Even if you don't have exposed `DbSet<T>` property, you can always use `Set<T>` method to get access to the corresponding `DbSet<T>`:

```
context.Set<BlogPost>().Add(new BlogPost { BlogId = blog1.Id, PostId = post1.Id });
```

or use directly the `Add` method of the `DbContext`:

```
context.Add(new BlogPost { BlogId = blog1.Id, PostId = post1.Id });
```

> Also, is it mandatory that I add a List navigation property to both the Blog and Post like in the example if I will only care about querying them from a single direction. i.e. Blog > Posts, don't need Post Blogs.

Navigation properties are not mandatory - see [Single Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#single-navigation-property) EF Core documentation topic. You can omit any of them. You don't even need a fluent configuration for the relationships because everything is by convention. But in case you use fluent configuration as in the example, make sure to use the `WithMany()` method without passing lambda/string navigation property (because you don't have it).

Answer (score 1):

> Would it hurt anything if I add a DbSet BlogPosts to the DbContext even though they don't do it in the example?

No! it wouldn't hurt! there is no problem of doing so! then you can use as follows:

```
context.BlogPosts.Add(new BlogPost { BlogId = blog1.Id, PostId = post1.Id });
```

> If I don't add the DbSet to the DbContext what would be the proper way to create a Blog and then add multiple Posts to it when seeding the database.

If you don't want to expose `BlogPosts` as `DbSet<>` then you can do as follows:

```
context.Set<BlogPost>().Add(new BlogPost { BlogId = blog1.Id, PostId = post1.Id });
```

> is it mandatory that I add a List navigation property to both the Blog and Post like in the example if I will only care about querying them from a single direction. i.e. Blog > Posts, don't need Post Blogs.

No! its not mandatory. You can do as follows:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the DbContext:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
}
```

Comment: you answered my question and I'm going to mark it correct, but I think you misunderstood question #2. I meant if I chose not to add BlogPosts entity as a DbSet what would be the proper way of creating BlogPosts when seeding the database. I kind of figured it out: blog1.BlogPosts.Add(new BlogPost { PostId = post1.Id }). Didn't even need to set the BlogId since we are adding to a Blog. I guess if I add BlogPosts as a DbSet I then can create them without going through the blog as well.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Actually I have not misunderstood the #2, I am not encouraging you to do so because this would not be a good practice. I have also said the alternative solution. if you really don't want to use dbSet<>, then you have to use pure sql command with entity framework `ExecuteCommand` feature. I am somewhat updating my answer. Thank you.

Comment: What I was trying to say was that you were thinking I wasn't adding the Blog entity as a DbSet. I definitely am adding this entity as a DbSet. I was questioning if I chose not to add BlogPost as a DbSet what would be the ways to create them since Context.BlogPosts.Add wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Read my answer again.

Comment: I was referring to #2, not #1. You say: "If you don't add Blog to DbSet<>". This is where I am saying the misunderstanding is.

Comment: Okay! got it! I have updated my answer again. By the way, hope your problem has been solved from two answers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185079/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-blake-rivell).